# How to create $http delete req in angularjs

Tags: html, angularjs, server, angularjs-ng-click

All i want is to delete a row of a table by clicking a button. I am diong something like this

```
  .controller('removeInput' , function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.remove = function(index){
      var inputId = {'inputId': $scope.inputId};
      $http.delete(baseUrl + '/input/' ,inputId, _auth)
      .success(function (){
        console.log('deleted');
      }).error(function(err){
        console.log(err);
      });
    };
  });
```

and in html its something like this

```
<tbody ng-controller = "input">
 <tr ng-repeat = "inputs in inputData">
  <td ng-model = "inputId">{{inputs.inputId}}</td>
  <td><img ng-src = "{{inputs.thumbnailUrl}}"/></td>
  <td>{{inputs.filename}}</td>
  <td></td>
  <td>{{inputs.updatedAt.date}}</td>
  <td ng-controller = "removeInput">
   <a class = "btn btn-option" ng-click = "remove(index)">
    <span class = "glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>
   </a>
  </td>
 </tr>
</tbody>
```

and its not working. Please suggest where I am wrong?

Comment: what is `_auth`? It is undefined in code shown. Also `not working` isn't a proper problem statement. What do you see when you inspect the actual request in browser dev tools network tab? Should find lots of clues there

Comment: _auth is global variable containing headers

Comment: wouldn't you want `remove(inputs.inputId)`?

Comment: headers config for CORS is all setted in this _auth variable

Comment: @Claies yup dats what i want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't really passing the correct value here.  It's not clear what `$scope.inputId` is, but it isn't the value of the item you are trying to remove.  Try this instead:

```
<a class = "btn btn-option" ng-click = "remove(inputs.inputId)">
```

and in the JavaScript:

```
$scope.remove = function(index){
  $http.delete(baseUrl + '/input/' + index, _auth)
  ....
```

Comment: its showing Object {status: 401, message: "Given api-key is not authorized!"} in console

Comment: or maybe you still need it in object form, let me edit the javascript again

Comment: I want id with the url. something like this '/input/6654' will be the url to pass

Comment: I have my code with yours and its still giving same error

Comment: let me try to edit it one last time; what you are describing in the comments here isn't what your function was doing before.